# my Routes are not passed from function to APP

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Im struggling for days with this.

I am dynamical generating my NAV from a wordpress JSON
(located in Components/headerComponent/header.js)

I am dynamically generating my Routes with the same JSON
(located in App.js)

In my Route, I am using Page as my template and sending a pageId state with useLocation
(located in Components/pages/Page.js)

The idea is that page catches the pageId and then fetches that page info from the JSON. If I hard code them  in app they work

the problem is MyRoutes are not being passed from the function into my app

Here is a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/live/yuooosn

````
```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import './Assets/css/default.min.css';
import Header from './Components/HeaderComponent/header';
import Footer from './Components/FooterComponent/footer';
import Page from './Components/Pages/Page';

function MyRoutes() {
  const [myrt, setMyrt] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('./JSON/main-menu')
      .then((res) => res.json())

      .then((json) => {
        setMyrt(json.items);
      });
  });

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Display Routes</h1>
      {Object.keys(myrt).map((ky, idx) => (
        <>
          <h2>{myrt[ky].slug}</h2>
          <Route exact path={myrt[ky].slug} component={Page} key={idx} />
        </>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Header />

          
          <MyRoutes />
          <Route path="/page" component={Page} />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;


function Page() {
  const { state:  { pageId }  } = useLocation();
    

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      
      <FetchContent  pageId={pageId} />
      
      <h3>Requested page ID: {pageId}</h3>
      
      
     </div>
  );
}
 
export default Page;
````

Comment: someone helped me, thank you! please come take credit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tungeric helped me on codesandbox by fixing below in MyRoutes function

```
 <Route exact path={`/${myrt[ky].slug}`} component={Page} key={idx} />
```